# How to add get parameters via htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How force add get parameter to url, that already have a get param? for example:

To url like this, which must have that ?a param, value doesnt matter:

`example.com/?a=value`

Make like this, value2 hardcoded:

`example.com/?a=value&b=value2`

I tried, yes its for index.php all:

`RewriteRule index.php/?a$ /index.php/?b=value2 [L,R,QSA]`

Comment: Confusingly, your example URLs do not match your directive. I've assumed `index.php` is part of the URL (since you state "yes its for index.php"), but I've excluded the path-info part since this is not in your example URLs and would seem unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule index.php/?a$ /index.php/?b=value2 [L,R,QSA]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) does not match against the query string. If you specifically need to check that the query string starts with the `a` parameter then you need a seperate condition that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

Assuming your URL actually contains `index.php` (your example doesn't?) and the URL-path doesn't end in a slash (ie. contain path-info) then you could do:

```
# Check that query string contains the "a" URL parameter anywhere
# but does not contain the "b" URL parameter already (avoid redirect loop)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \ba=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\bb=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?b=value2 [QSA,R,L]
```

The `\b` matches a *word boundary*, so `a` can only match at the start of the query string or at the start of a URL parameter (after `&`).

The `QSA` flag appends (ie. merges) the original query string from the request. So, it will redirect from `/index.php?a=value` to `/index.php?b=value2&a=value` - note that the original query string is *appended*.

If you specifically wish to keep the URL parameters in the original order and append the new value to the end then you could change the `RewriteRule` to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&b=value2 [R,L]
```

Now the result would be `/index.php?a=value&b=value2`.